# how to install libsnappy.so.1?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

Im working with docker to host a local database for a website.
When running my executable for my local database it gives an error about libsnappy.so.1

Ive tried running `apt-get install -y snapd`.

Here is the code I am running.

```
sudo docker build --tag=tx1 .
```

When running the below

```
sudo docker run -t -i -p 8080:80 tx1
```

It gives the error

```
./next9: error while loading shared libraries: libsnappy.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

here is my docker file if anyone wants to see

```
#Download base image ubuntu 18.04
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# ENTRYPOINT ["/docker/tx1"]

# Update Ubuntu Software repository
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y snapd; ldconfig
#  apt-get install -y gnome-terminal 
WORKDIR /

COPY . /
EXPOSE 80
CMD  chmod 777 build; ./build
```

build

```
#!/bin/bash
./next9 & ./main
```

Answer (score 1):

edit you `apt` command like this:

```
apt-get install -y snapd libsnappy1
```

that should fix it